# "Wake on LAN" my Mac Mini from my PC?

Tags: mac, network, windows, sleep-wake, pc

I would like to be able to use the Wake On LAN feature to wake up my Mac Mini from my Windows PC, and I have tried two different programs (Solar Winds and NirSoft) but it is not working.

1. I have already enabled "Wake for Network Access" in the settings on my Mac Mini.
2. I have Mac Mini connected to my (Linksys) router with an Ethernet cable.
3. I have a Windows 10 PC connected to the same router over WiFi.
4. I can use VNC to screen share and control my Mac Mini from my PC. This works really well.
5. I can ping the Mac Mini (when it is on) from my PC and it responds.

Any ideas on how to close the loop on this?

Answer (score -1):

You normally have to access a shared resource on the Mac rather than use a magic packet.

The simplest way is to set up file sharing (allowing SMB for the PC) and try to access that from the PC.  This could be any folder you like so you do not have to worry about it being visible to others on the network and can (should) be password protected.

Other things that should work are:

- Shared printers / scanners
- Music
- Music play lists
- Screen sharing (I think but that may have been via VNC on the Mac)